# Cycle a class trough children of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have some sort of carousel. I have a class called `active` that makes a certain item visible. I would like to cycle trough them. Is there a way to check which child has the active class so i can move the active class to the next one.

example html:

```html
<div class="carouselContainer">
    <div class="carouselItemDiv">
        <img src="" loading="eager" data-showtime="5000" class="carouselItem">
    </div>
    <div class="carouselItemDiv">
        <img src="" loading="eager" data-showtime="5000" class="carouselItem active">
    </div>
    <div class="carouselItemDiv">
        <img src="" loading="eager" data-showtime="5000" class="carouselItem">
    </div>
    <div class="carouselItemDiv">
        <img src="" loading="eager" data-showtime="5000" class="carouselItem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. There are a few ways to solve it.  One way is to grab all the items, check them individually, and then mark the next one as active.

```
// grab all the carousel items
var items = document.querySelector(".carouselContainer")
    .querySelectorAll(".carouselItemDiv");
    
// loop thru each of the carousel items
for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){

  // if the item is active
  if ( items[i].classList.contains("active") ){

    // mark it inactive
    items[i].classList.remove("active");

    // if last item in list, mark the first item active
    if ( i == items.length - 1 ){
      items[0].classList.add("active");
    }
    // otherwise mark the next item active
    else {
      items[i+1].classList.add("active")
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

You can also rely on the dom, but you trade a little structural flexibility this way.

```
// grab the active item
var item = document.querySelector(".carouselItemDiv.active");

// mark it inactive
item.classList.remove("active");

// if there's an item after it, mark it active    
if ( item.nextElementSibling ){
  item.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
} 
// otherwise mark the first carousel item active
else {
  document.querySelector(".carouselItemDiv").classList.add("active");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know nextElementSibling existed. I was very much overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a div has the class "active" using this code:

```
var carouselItemDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("carouselItemDiv");

for (var i = 0; i < carouselItemDivs.length; i++) {
    if (carouselItemDivs[i].classList.contains("active") {
        // carouselItemDivs[i] has the class "active"
        // Do something
    }
}
```